# Angular cli how to install only localy as devdependency

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is it possible to use the angular cli without installing it globally only in the local project directory as devdependency only?

If yes how can I then call the cli commands?

I don't want to install the cli globaly, because of our build server. 
When I have x different angular pages and each page is build with an other cli version then I think its not working to deploy each site with the same build server, when the cli is installed globaly on that server.

Or are there any other solutions for such a problem?

Comment: are you on linux or windows?

Comment: I am using a windows system

Comment: Theoretically it's possible, yes. The package for the cli itself is installed in `node_modules` for the project and there is of course a `.bin` directory within containing `ng` and `ngc` etc etc. So it's really a question of setting up your environment to execute from `node_modules/.bin` in your project directory. Got to be a question that answers that one around here somewhere.

Comment: Any command executed via the npm scripts mechanism will use the version in `node_modules/.bin` preferentially, so `{"start": "ng serve"}` will use the locally installed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand this post:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5955#issuecomment-302742638

you install the cli globaly and add the cli also as dev dependency, when the dev dependency version is lower than the global version - the cli will use the local version (dev dependencies).